# Getting this "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied" even I ran the command prompt as administrator

Tags: python-3.x

I did 
pip install zipline
and the error I got was

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

I did search in here in stackoverflow and it seems that the solution is
to run the command prompt as administrator and install it.
However, I did that exactly and still got this error. What could be the problem?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, the easiest and best supported way to install zipline is to use **Conda**.

package manager, which comes as part of Continuum Analytics’ **Anaconda** distribution.

The primary advantage of using Conda over pip is that conda natively understands the complex binary dependencies of packages like **numpy** and **scipy**. This means that conda can install Zipline and its dependencies without requiring the use of a second tool to acquire Zipline’s non-Python dependencies.
after installing coda you can use Quantopian and run following command

```
conda install -c Quantopian zipline
```

for more information visit this [link](http://www.zipline.io/install.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the Python 3.6 version and I think currently the zipline library does not work in 3.6 version. And with regard to installing conda, how would you do that? I originally installed Python through Anaconda distribution through their website. So then, that means I already have conda installed right?

Comment: you try installing through conda..?

Comment: if you still installing using pip3 first check all dependencies that are  required.. and run your command  as a admin user...hope this help